# chkconfig does not display runlevel links correctly

Tags: linux, debian, chkconfig

I am using chkconfig to manipulate runlevel links on my Debian System (LSBInitScripts). I have noticed some inconsistencies, for example

According to chkconfig, the script `umountiscsi.sh` is turned off in all runlevels:

```
chkconfig umountiscsi.sh --list
umountiscsi.sh            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

however, I can see the symlinks in `/etc/rc1.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/`

```
ls -lAhF /etc/rc{1,6}.d/*umountiscsi.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jul 23 13:38 /etc/rc1.d/K01umountiscsi.sh -> ../init.d/umountiscsi.sh*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jul 23 13:38 /etc/rc6.d/K01umountiscsi.sh -> ../init.d/umountiscsi.sh*
```

the symlinks in `rc1.d` and `rc6.d` mean, that this script will be run in runlevel 1 and 6 (which is the way it is supposed to be run). But why does chkconfig not display it correctly ?

Comment: I believe chkconfig only checks for the link scripts that start with S to mark then on.

Comment: does it mean then, that I cannot use chkconfig to manage K init scripts (runlevels 0 and 6)?

Comment: chkconfig is telling you the truth. According to what ls says, umountiscsi is **not** started in any runlevel, which is exactly what chkconfig says. What would you like chkconfig to report differently than it is?

Comment: In my understanding, according to `ls`, the script `umountiscsi` is being run (started) in runlevels 1 and 6. So I would have expected that chkconfig reports `1:on` and `6:on`.

Comment: Your understanding is mistaken: the `K??` links **stop** umountiscsi if it is running at the transition to runlevels 1 and 6. Please comment on my answer if there is something unclear there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From /etc/rc?.d/README:

> To disable a service in this runlevel, rename its script in this
>   directory so that the new name begins with a 'K' and a two-digit
>   number, and run 'update-rc.d script defaults' to reorder the scripts
>   according to dependencies.

Files starting with `S` are started, and those with `K` are killed if running prior to the runlevel switch. This is why there is a `K` type, it stops something that may be running instead of doing nothing which would happen if there was no `[SK]??unmountiscsi.sh` present.

Comment: thanks, I understand the meaning of S and K init scripts. My question was more about how to use chkconfig to manage K scripts in runlevels 0 and 6.